# Is there a meaningful difference between "abjure" and "abnegate"?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

Can *abjure* and *abnegate* be used interchangeably?

I see that *abjure* is defined as "solemnly renounce (a belief, cause, or claim)" and *abnegate* as "renounce or reject (something desired or valuable)."

Are the nuances around renouncing "solemnly" or renouncing something "desired" meaningful in how these words are commonly used?

Comment: Merriam-Webster provides [advice](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abjure) on choosing the right synonym for abjure, although it doesn't include abnegate. Despite that, there's certainly a lot of overlap. Without knowing your context, I'd suggest reading the examples in Lexico and seeing which is closest to what you want.

Comment: Let's start with *how these words are commonly used*. They're not. They are not old friends, We were never close. Well, not in that way. But two rules of mine: if there exist two English words, they can't be quite identical, so no random swapping. And no using words I have to slow down to enunciate. They cannot be friends, but I already said that.

Comment: The dictionary definitions you quote seem to indicate the difference. Abjure is used for beliefs, while abnegate is used for things.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think of these two verbs as having particularly similar meanings—perhaps because I associate *abnegate* with *self-abnegation* (that is, self-denial) and *abjure* with the Dutch [Act of Abjuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_of_Abjuration) of 1581. *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) seems to agree with my impression, as it places the two words in a separate bundles of synonyms:

> **abjure. Abjure, renounce, forswear, recant, retract** are synonymous when they agree in meaning to abandon irrevocably and, usually, with solemnity or publicity. Except in the extended senses of *abjure*, *renounce*, and *forswear*, they all imply the recall of one's word. **Abjure** and **renounce** are scarcely distinguishable when they imply solemn repudiation as of an oath or vow. ... In their extended senses, however, abjure distinctively suggests deliberate rejection or avoidance; renounce specifically connotes disclaiming or disowning; as, to *abjure* force; to *renounce* one's principles. ...
>
> ...
>
> **forgo,** *also* **forego. Forgo** (*or* **forego**), **forebear, abnegate, eschew, sacrifice** come into comparison when they denote to deny oneself something for the sake of an end. ... One **abnegates** what is intrinsically good but not consistent with one's aims, principles, or limitations. "To treat English poetry {in teaching literature} as though it had died with Tennyson. . .is to *abnegate* high hope for the sake of a barren convenience" (*Quiller-Couch*). In its narrower and more common signification, *abnegate* implies renunciation or self-effacement, but this distinction is not as commonly maintained in the verb as in the derivative noun *abnegation*.

The followup edition of this reference work, *Merrriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984) leaves the coverage of both words (and their synonyms) virtually unchanged.

S.I. Hayakawa, *Modern Guide to Synonyms and Related Words* (1968) doesn't address abnegate at all, but puts *abjure* in a set of synonyms led by *forswear*:

> **forswear, abjure, disavow, disclaim, disown, recant, retract, take back[.]** These words apply when a person rejects something, gives up his past behavior, or withdraws from a previously stated stand or belief. ... Where *forswear* can suggest moral resolve or penitence, **abjure** is more forceful in sometimes implying an angry rejection; it also referred once to renunciation under oath, but less often applies in this way now: a union official who *abjured* mediation as a solution to the dispute, especially considering the unwillingness of management to negotiate; bitter disappointments that made him *abjure* marriage in favor of a series of affairs.

James Fernald, *Funk & Wagnalls Standard Handbook of Synonyms, Antonyms, and Prepositions* (1947) likewise is silent on *abnegate*, but it assigns *abjure* to two different bundles of synonyms, one headed by *abandon* and the other by *renounce*:

> **ABANDON** [and 24 related terms, including *abjure*]. ... A ruler might *cede* his territory, *desert* his followers, ***abjure*** or *renounce* his religion, *relinquish* his titles, *abandon* his designs, *recant* his confession.
>
> ...
>
> **RENOUNCE** [and 15 related terms, including *abjure*]. ***Abjure***, *discard*, *forswear*, *recall*, *recant*, *renounce*, *retract*, and *revoke*, like *abandon*, imply some previous connection. ... ***Abjure*** is etymologically the exact equivalent of the Saxon forswear, signifying to put away formally and under oath, as an error, heresy, or evil practice, or a condemned and detested person. A man ***abjures*** his religion, *recants* his belief, ***abjures*** or *renounces* his allegiance, repudiate his wife, renounces old habits, retracts a false statement. ... A native of the United States cannot ***abjure*** or *renounce* allegiance to the King of England, but will promptly *deny* it.

The upshot of these various treatments of *abjure* is that it indicates a more or less formal act of disavowal or rejection of the abjurer's previous belief or allegiance, whereas *abnegate* seems to emphasize a commitment to do without something that the abnegator had previously enjoyed.